# Get data from firebase DB into string inside my program Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase DB and save data to a string inside my program. All I come across is that I can only view data in a list but find no good guide how to get data without showing all data for the user first. I want it to be run in the background without the user having to see when data is retrieved. In the image below I show what data I want to store inside a string and then use that string to do what I want it to do.

This is the data I want to store inside my string

[image]

You can see the blue rings. The data inside the blue rings is what I want to store inside a string or in a string array.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);


    firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();




    listan = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



    DatabaseReference datarefere = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(My URL to database");


    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaselist = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            datarefere
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {



            TextView textview = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            textview.setText(model);


        }
    };

    listan.setAdapter(firebaselist);


    listan.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            TextView listan = (TextView) view;
            String plats = listan.getText().toString();




        }
    });
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}
```

In this case i did use listview. The user click on an item inside the list and I save the data to a string. But i dont want to do like that all the time. I want to save data into a string in the background. The user dont need to know or see that it happens.

Comment: What did you've tried till now? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something that can help you is [this google developer link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio) about how to setup Firebase and other DBs. I hope this helps.